# Расположение ImageView по центру

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте! Хотелось бы узнать каким способом разместить `ImageView` по центру экрана при помощи java-кода, не прибегая к использованию параметра `android:scaleType`? Структура `xml`-проекта такая:

```
<ScrollView
...>
<Relativelayout
...>
<Linearlayout
<ImageView
.../>
</Linearlayout>
</Relativelayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: А вариант проставить `scaleType` программно подойдёт?...

Answer (score 1):

У вас ImageView вложен в контейнер Linearlayout. Укажите для него gravity

Пример:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Там еще скролл для которого может потребоваться атрибут android:fillViewport="true" иначе изображение будет не центрировано по высоте

Answer (score 1):

с помощью java: `img.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)` или

```
Relative/Frame/LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = 
   new R/F/L.LayoutParams (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

дальше
для RelativeLayout: `lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT)`
для FrameLayout и LinearLayout: `lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER`

и `img.setLayoutParams(lp);`